# Ajax is losing sessions

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I upgraded my Symfony application from Symfony 4.0.7 to Symfony 4.1 and after that AJAX calls are losing sessions values.

I have about 6 ajax requests called at the same time. First of them is going fine but others are losing session values. It happened only after migration to Symfony 4.1 and only for AJAX calls. Any ideas?

edit: It happens only with ajax called at the same time. WHen I add eg 100 miliseconds delay between calling ajax then all works fine.

edit2: it happens on 4 different servers. 2 dev servers, 1 test server and 1 live server. all of them run on NGINX and php7

Comment: What server env are you experiencing this on? Would be interesting to know if this is symfony's local one or apache or whatever. Would be even more interesting to know if this happens on different server instances / setups as that would indicate if it's the server's config or symfony you need to look at...

Comment: @Bananaapple I've updated my post

Comment: Try running the local `php bin/console server:run` to see if you still get it. Also, since it's to do with JS try it on different browsers.

Comment: Maybe this: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-session-improvements

Comment: Happend to me in Laravel. I don't know how to fix this but  this is happen let's say you do an ajax request and before finish that ajax request you do an another ajax request and it return before first ajax request then when the  first ajax request finish session also will erased. so I had to wait to send second ajax request until first one finished

Comment: @Bananaapple it was tested on different browsers and effect is the same

Comment: @Alex and how this will help me? I've read that articles many tuimes before and there is nothing directly connected to my problem. Only thing which we can learn from there that they changed sessions somehow and now I have the problem.

Comment: @SupunPraneeth as I said before: it is working fine on Symfony 4.0.7 so this is the problem of current version of symfony not php in general. As I also said before it works fine when I add delay between AJAXs but I need those AJAX to be run more less at the same time.

Comment: @nospor, sorry if this is not helpful, I thought you could at least check that all your code have `hasSession()`. It's very strange that it doesn't work only in case of the same time, it looks like you've some additional config for js set up. How do you do ajax call?

Comment: I feel like it would work in case `setTimeout( doAjaxCall, 0)` - it's probably workaround for you

Comment: @Alex ajax calls are really simple ajaxs one after another. Setting delay for 0 will not work: **as I said in my first post** it works only for bigger delays like 100ms and this is depending on response time so it is not a constant number and this is not a workaround for my situation

Comment: I though I was loosing it, this is the first topic with a description which matches my problem. I have a bit more tests done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188446/session-values-randomly-gone-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was because of session fixation strategy which was changing session ID each request and AJAX requests each after another did have time to update the new ID.

A solution was quite simple, just setting `session_fixation_strategy: none`.

Comment: This is not a permanent solution, but wroks for me for now :)

Comment: @Martijn Glad I could help a little :)

Comment: How can I set session_fixation_strategy: none ??

Comment: @Saurabh you need to set it in security.yml file

session_fixation_strategy: none

Comment: @nospor: thanks for the reply, I went through the documentation and it says "not recommended". Why? Would it make it vulnerable ?

Comment: @nospor: I am facing same situation, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255053/how-to-stop-perfoming-on-xhr-requests-when-the-user-is-logout-in-symfony

Comment: @Saurabh it is not recomended as this is less secure. Still, for me it works and at this point I need this

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Causes could be, as follows:**:

> **Allow to cache requests that use sessions**:

Whenever the session is started during a request, Symfony turns the response into a private non-cacheable response to prevent leaking private information. However, even requests making use of the session can be cached under some circumstances.

For example, information related to some user group could be cached for all the users belonging to that group. Handling these advanced caching scenarios is out of the scope of Symfony, but they can be solved with the FOSHttpCacheBundle.

In order to disable the default Symfony behavior that makes requests using the session uncacheable, in Symfony 4.1 we added the NO_AUTO_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER header that you can add to response:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\AbstractSessionListener;
$response->headers->set(AbstractSessionListener::NO_AUTO_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, 'true');
```

> **Deprecate some uses of Request::getSession()**

Using Request::getSession() when no session exists has been deprecated in Symfony 4.1 and it will throw an exception in Symfony 5.0. The solution is to always check first if a session exists with the Request::hasSession() method:

```
if ($request->hasSession() && ($session = $request->getSession())) {
    $session->set('some_key', 'some_value');
}
```

More on Ref: [Here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-session-improvements).

Comment: Unfortunatelly adding that option to response doesnt fix the problem :(

Comment: Where to write the `$response` line in the code? Is there a way to globally set this header?

Comment: You may refer to this URL:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony

Answer (score 1):

Have you check **XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials**?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

What about the response Headers?

1. Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
2. Connection: keep-alive
3. set-cookie: ...

Are these requests' session id equal?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Maybe you need set the session cookie before ajax request.

**Here is a example:**

ajax.php

```
<?php
function getSessionIdentifier()
{
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['identifier'])) {
        $_SESSION['identifier'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
    }
    return $_SESSION['identifier'];
}

echo json_encode([
    'identifier' => getSessionIdentifier()
]);
```

start-without-session.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>start without session</title></head>
<body>
<script>
let started;
const cookie = () => '[' + document.cookie + ']';
const track = () => {
    started = started || (new Date()).getTime();
    return ((new Date()).getTime() - started) + 'ms';
};

const send = (index) => {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', '/ajax.php');

    console.log(track(), 'send', index, cookie());

    req.addEventListener("load", () => {
        console.log(track(), 'receive', index, cookie(), req.responseText);
    });

    req.send();
}

document.cookie = "PHPSESSID=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";

console.log(track(), 'begin', cookie());
const len1 = 5;
const len2 = 10;
Array.from({length: len1}).forEach((v, i) => send(i));
console.log(track(), 'delay');
Array.from({length: len2}).forEach((v, j) => window.setTimeout(() => send(j + len1), j * 10));
</script>
</body></html>
```

[image]

start-with-session.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['identifier'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>start with session</title></head>
<body>
<script>
let started;
const cookie = () => '[' + document.cookie + ']';
const track = () => {
    started = started || (new Date()).getTime();
    return ((new Date()).getTime() - started) + 'ms';
};

const send = (index) => {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', '/ajax.php');

    console.log(track(), 'send', index, cookie());

    req.addEventListener("load", () => {
        console.log(track(), 'receive', index, cookie(), req.responseText);
    });

    req.send();
}

//
// document.cookie = "PHPSESSID=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
//

console.log(track(), 'begin', cookie());
const len1 = 5;
const len2 = 10;
Array.from({length: len1}).forEach((v, i) => send(i));
console.log(track(), 'delay');
Array.from({length: len2}).forEach((v, j) => window.setTimeout(() => send(j + len1), j * 10));
</script>
</body></html>
```

[image]

I'm not 100% sure this is the same situation. need more info.

Comment: So, do you suggest that when I send ajax with delays cookies are sent automatically and when I send ajax exactly the same way, except that I do not do any delays, I need to set cookie manually?

Comment: In php session_start() will set a cookie named PHPSESSID automatically. This cookie is used to identify session.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials tell the browser send ajax request with this session cookie.

Comment: I know that. THats why I am asking you: so are you saying that when I send ajax one after another I need to set it manually? Because as I said few times before, when I sent AJAXs with delays all is working fine without setting any additional things

Comment: no. What I'm saying is that you need set the session cookie before all these ajax requests. And all these ajax request send with same session cookie.

Comment: So I am asking why I do not have to set this when I call AJAXs with delays?

Comment: @nospor , I added more details in the answer. But I'm not sure this is the same situation as yours. We need more info.

Comment: Thank you for your update Anthony. I JQuery to send AJAX. It sends cookies automatically with every request. I still think this is a fault of Symfony upgrade, especially that in 4.1 they did some session changes. With Symfony 4.0.7 this immediate ajax works perfectly fine. I do not change ajax calls. What I change is  SF version and then it stops to work.

Answer (score 0):

You must not launch all the AJAX requests on the same time when your application depends on live cookies.
Maybe the symfony uses something in the cookies to do the CSRF Token work.

The reason why it worked with a 100ms timeout between the request is that the first one had time to parse the response and change the cookies with that response, and the next request used the new cookies.

what you need to do is:

- make the second AJAX call a callback from the first, the third one a callback from the second and so on...

OR

- find out what is in the cookies that needs to be up to date to not generate an error and disable it. But take in count that this protection is in place for a reason and you might expose your application to a security breach if disabled.
  it might help us figuring the issue if you provide the faulty AJAX calls responses (inpect->network in browser)

OR

- Make your ajax call use JWT based middleware (witch is complicated if you never done it before) so it uses a stateless session.

Comment: Simple question: why it does work with symfony 4.0.7 and after upgrade to symfony 4.1 it stop to work? For me this is symfony bug not ajax.

Comment: ad1) I can not do this. Those ajax calls are for charts data. Some charts can generate quicker than others. I can not generate chart after chart because it can take much longer time to display all charts. ad2) I need that missing data for authentication. I can not ignore them. ad3) Yes, that could be a solution but still I think this is SF4.1 upgrade fault and I do not want to waste time to introduce JWT when is not needed

Comment: ad1) loading the charts one by one from the same symfony installation is faster than loading all of them at once. doing this, you also avoid risking a timeout on one of the ajax request. Try Benchmarking the two methods. you will be surprised by the results

Comment: With that solution clients will have to wait longer to see charts. The idea is that they can see some "faster" charts earlier if possible and it worked perfectly fine for Sf 4.0.7