# Session values randomly gone/back

Tags: php, symfony, session

We work with the Symfony framework (V4.1.3) and our session values (seemingly) randomly disappear/re-appear. Sometimes within seconds it's gone/back, sometimes it's back/gone after a few minutes.

We just do a dump of the session values, nothing else. Thusfar it appears 100% random.

- This problem exists in various browsers, on my local machine and on the server.
- We use Symfony's wrapper. `$_SESSION` always has a few values, but only when '_sf2_attributes' is set, `$session->all()` return the values
- session.save_handler and session.save_path have proper values
- `session_id()` always returns a unique id, wether it returns the data or not
- If we keep refreshing it'll disappear, regardless of interval between refreshes. Could take 1 reload, could take 6.
- If we keep refreshing it'll re-appear, regardless of interval between refreshes. Could take 1 reload, could take 6.
- The session contains one (string)key=>(int)value
- Nowhere in the project the session is used. Currently, the `dump($session->all())` is the only session related code.
- memcache isn't present
- If I set a $_SESSION value manually, and reload it's gone. Even if the other values come back, the just set element is still gone.
- there are no load balancers Local and on the testserver
- When I have two browser open, each with a session, and reload quickly it's gone in one, but the other still exists.

I would like a consistent session. Anyone got a suggestion?

Comment: Where is it happening, on your local dev machine? Don't you have multiple servers behind a load balancer, do you? :)

Comment: there are no loadbalancers (added that to the question). I'll go read the duplicate

Comment: It is not the same as the suggested duplicate. Having a unique session ID each load is good, that topic suggests it's bad. They never have the data, I sometimes have the data :)

Comment: I applied the solution in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925212/ajax-is-losing-sessions topic. Not the best solution, but a working one.